# Why is my C++ vector resizing and appending a new vector instead of changing in place?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm doing some LeetCode questions, and I'm not sure why my vector is resizing. Here's relevant portions of my code:

```
    void turnToString(std::vector<int> & charFreq, std::string & freqStr)
    {
        for(int i : charFreq)
            freqStr.append(std::to_string(i));
        std::cout << freqStr << std::endl;
    }

    std::vector<int> charFreq (26,0);
    for(int i = 0, j = p.size() - 1; j < s.size(); i++, j++)
    {
        charFreq[s[j] -'a']++;
        turnToString(charFreq, str);
        if(str == freqStr)
            res.push_back(i);
        charFreq[s[i]-'a']--;
    }
```

Everything compiles fine, but in my turnToString() function, when I print out the frequency vector as a string, it keeps doubling:
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L6q0x.png)

I'm not sure why it's acting like this. My intention was for the vector to stay a size of 26 and change the frequencies in place as I iterate through 's'. Instead, it's appending a new frequency array to my vector. I know I can fix this with just using a regular array, but thought I'd use this as a learning opportunity. Why is this happening and what can I do to fix it w/o using a different data structure?

Comment: You're printing the string, not the `vector`. And the string does get modified in the function

Comment: presumably you want `freqStr.clear()` at the start of `turnToString`

Answer (score 0):

For each entry in charFreq, you append that entry to freqStr:

```
freqStr.append(std::to_string(i));
```

so `str` (outside the function) will grow more and more.